# A student who should know how to do this, kirchhoff's edition

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

We know that the voltage of the volt meter gives 2V and the ammeter is 2A. We must find I1 and I2, and I'm at a loss as to what the voltage can be used for. Especially considering the correction of this exercice, uses R1 * I1 -6 = 2. Why would I1 pass through R1, wouldn't it be another current completely?

[image]

My mistake, R1 being 4 ohm, R2 1 ohm and we are looking for R

Comment: there is no R1 in your diagram

Comment: Applying the simplest analysis method there is, we find that: R=3Ω, VR=12V, I1=-2A, I2=-2A

Comment: Assuming that the measuring instruments are ideal, then there is no interaction between them and the rest of the circuit. The network can be studied with the simple but laborious superposition principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$I_1\$ cannot pass through the voltmeter, so all of it must pass through the 4 ohm resistor. (KCL)